# Use off()-method on mouseover() and mouseout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

As my title shows I've problem using the off-method in JQuery combined with mouseover/mouseout.

My HTML-code(the relevant part):

```
 <h3>Hover</h3>
 <p id="hover">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
 <button id="off">Press the button</button>
```

My JQuery-code(the relevant part):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hover").mouseover(function(){
         $("#hover").css("background-color", "green");
   });
   $("#hover").mouseout(function(){
        $("#hover").css("background-color", "lightblue");
   });
   $("#off").click(function(){
        $("#hover").off("click");
    });
});
```

The "hover-part" works fine. But when i press the button, which supposed to stop the mouseover and mouseout-methods to stop, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery's [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), to set off the event handlers like this:

```
$("#hover").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hover").mouseover(function(){
         $(this).css("background-color", "green");
   });
   $("#hover").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
   });
   $("#off").click(function(){
        $("#hover").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Hover</h3>
 <p id="hover">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
 <button id="off">Press the button</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Waltswen - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

The element has no `click` event listener added to, but `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Thus, no `off()` has no effect. Use:

```
$("#hover").off("mouseover mouseout");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hover").mouseover(function(){
         $("#hover").css("background-color", "green");
   });
   $("#hover").mouseout(function(){
        $("#hover").css("background-color", "lightblue");
   });
   $("#off").click(function(){
        $("#hover").off("mouseover mouseout");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Hover</h3>
 <p id="hover">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
 <button id="off">Press the button</button>
```